# Bash Text Parsing a HIVE DDL

Tags: bash, parsing, hive, dynamic-sql, ddl

I have repeating group of below text which is essentially a describe extened output from 2 hadoop hive tables tablea1 and tablea2 and showing its properties.

```
Detailed Table Information      Table(tableName:tablea1, dbName:default, owner:eedc_hdp_s_d-itm-e, createTime:1519807981, lastAccessTime:0, retention:0, sd:StorageDescriptor(cols:[FieldSchema(name:col1, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:col2, type:int, comment:null)], location:hdfs://DBDP-Dev/apps/hive/warehouse/tablea1, inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat, compressed:false, numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, parameters:{serialization.format=1}), bucketCols:[], sortCols:[], parameters:{}, skewedInfo:SkewedInfo(skewedColNames:[], skewedColValues:[], skewedColValueLocationMaps:{}), storedAsSubDirectories:false), partitionKeys:[], parameters:{totalSize=0, rawDataSize=0, numRows=0, COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE={"BASIC_STATS":"true"}, numFiles=0, transient_lastDdlTime=1519807981}, viewOriginalText:null, viewExpandedText:null, tableType:MANAGED_TABLE)


Detailed Table Information      Table(tableName:tablea2, dbName:default, owner:eedc_hdp_s_d-itm-e, createTime:1519807982, lastAccessTime:0, retention:0, sd:StorageDescriptor(cols:[FieldSchema(name:col3, type:int, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:col4, type:int, comment:null)], location:hdfs://DBDP-Dev/apps/hive/warehouse/tablea2, inputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat, outputFormat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat, compressed:false, numBuckets:-1, serdeInfo:SerDeInfo(name:null, serializationLib:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, parameters:{serialization.format=1}), bucketCols:[], sortCols:[], parameters:{}, skewedInfo:SkewedInfo(skewedColNames:[], skewedColValues:[], skewedColValueLocationMaps:{}), storedAsSubDirectories:false), partitionKeys:[], parameters:{totalSize=0, rawDataSize=0, numRows=0, COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE={"BASIC_STATS":"true"}, numFiles=0, transient_lastDdlTime=1519807982}, viewOriginalText:null, viewExpandedText:null, tableType:MANAGED_TABLE)
Time taken: 0.08 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

I am trying to generate a tablename|columnname from the above data like below

```
tablea1|col1
tablea1|col2
tablea2|col3
tablea2|col4
```

I was able to generate 2 commands to generate each of columns

```
grep -o 'Table(tableName:[^,]*' sample_file  | awk -F ':' '{ print $2}'
```

Gives first column

```
tablea1
tablea2

grep -o 'FieldSchema(name:[^,]*' sample_file | awk -F ':' '{ print $2}' | uniq
```

Gives second column

```
col1
col2
col3
col4
```

But i am unable to proceed further and get the desired output

```
tablea1|col1
tablea1|col2
tablea2|col3
tablea2|col4
```

Can you please help . Or is there an easier way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `-n` option of grep along with `-o` to also carry the line numbers of the match.

Then use the `join` command by joining with the line number as a key to get the desired output . Refer:[Join](https://shapeshed.com/unix-join/) to understand the arguments used.

```
grep -on 'Table(tableName:[^,]*' sample_file  | awk -F ':' '{ OFS="|";print $1,$3}'  >file1

grep -on 'FieldSchema(name:[^,]*' sample_file | awk -F ':' '{ OFS="|";print $1,$3}'  >file2

join -t "|" -1 1 -2 1 -o '1.2,2.2'   <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

we could also write a `REGEXP` or `awk` one-liner to get the desired result, but I feel the above would be much cleaner.